# join two data files in HDFS with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I have two datasets which are already partitioned using same partitioner and stored in HDFS. These datasets are output of two different Spark jobs which we don't have control. Now, I wan to join these two datasets to produce different information.

```
Example:

Data Set 1:
ORDER_ID  CUSTOMER_ID ITEMS
OD1        C1          1,2,3   -> partition 0
OD2        C2          3,4,5   -> partition 0
OD3        C4          1,2,3   -> partition 1
OD4        C3          1,3     -> partition 1

Data Set 1:
ORDER_ID  CUSTOMER_ID  REFUND_ITEMS
OD1        C1          1     -> partition 0
OD2        C2          5     -> partition 0
OD3        C4          2,3   -> partition 1
OD4        C3          3     -> partition 1

Options are:

1) Create two RDDs from the datasets and join them.
2) Create one RDD using one of the dataset.
   -> For each partition in the RDD get the actual partition id i.e OD1 -> 0, OD3 -> 1 (using some custom logic)
   ->  Load data from HDFS for that partition for dataset 2
   -> Iterate over both the dataset and produce combined result.

For option 2 I don't know how to read a specific file form HDFS in the Spark executor. (I have the full URI for location of the file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating 2 dataframes and join them using SQL. Please find the code below.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder

// For implicit conversions from RDDs to DataFrames
import spark.implicits._

case class struc_dataset(ORDER_ID: String,CUSTOMER_ID: String, ITEMS:String)

//Read file1
val File1DF = spark.sparkContext
   .textFile("temp/src/file1.txt")
   .map(_.split("\t"))
   .map(attributes => struc_dataset(attributes(0), attributes(1),attributes(3))).toDF()

//Register as Temp view - Dataset1
File1DF.createOrReplaceTempView("Datset1")

//Read file2
val File2DF = spark.sparkContext
   .textFile("temp/src/file2.txt")
   .map(_.split("\t"))
   .map(attributes => struc_dataset(attributes(0),attributes(1),attributes(3))).toDF()

//Register as Temp view - Dataset2
File2DF.createOrReplaceTempView("Datset2")

// SQL statement to create final dataframe (JOIN)
val finalDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Dataset1 ds1 JOIN Dataset2 ds2 on ds1.ORDER_ID=ds2.ORDER_ID AND ds1.CUSTOMER_ID=ds2.CUSTOMER_ID")

finalDF.show()
```